# Can I trust my cfa results if the variance-covariance matrix does not appear to be positive definite?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, factor-analysis, structural-equation-model

I am trying to create a structural equation model that tests the structure of latent variables underlying a big 5 dataset found on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/tunguz/big-five-personality-test). More specifically, I would like to replicate a finding which suggests that common method variance (e.g., response biases) inflate the often observed high intercorrelations between the manifest variables/items of the big 5 [(Chang, Connelly & Geeza (2012)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21967007).

```
big5_CFAmodel_cmv <-'EXTRA =~ EXT1 + EXT2 + EXT3 + EXT4 + EXT5 + EXT7 + EXT8 + EXT9 + EXT10 
                     AGREE =~ AGR1 + AGR2 + AGR4 + AGR5 + AGR6 + AGR7 + AGR8 + AGR9 + AGR10 
                     EMO   =~ EST1 + EST2 + EST3 + EST5 + EST6 + EST7 + EST8 + EST9 + EST10 
                     OPEN  =~ OPN1 + OPN2 + OPN3 + OPN5 + OPN6 + OPN7 + OPN8 + OPN9 + OPN10 
                     CON   =~ CSN1 + CSN2 + CSN3 + CSN4 + CSN5 + CSN6 + CSN7 + CSN8 + CSN9  
                     CMV   =~ EXT1 + EXT2 + EXT3 + EXT4 + EXT5 + EXT7 + EXT8 + EXT9 + EXT10 + AGR1 + AGR2 + AGR4 + AGR5 + AGR6 + AGR7 + AGR8 + AGR9 + AGR10 + CSN1 + CSN2 + CSN3 + CSN4 + CSN5 + CSN6 + CSN7 + CSN8 + CSN9 + EST1 + EST2 + EST3 + EST5 + EST6 + EST7 + EST8 + EST9 + EST10 + OPN1 + OPN2 + OPN3 + OPN5 + OPN6 + OPN7 + OPN8 + OPN9 + OPN10 '

big5_CFA_cmv <- cfa(model = big5_CFAmodel_cmv,
                        data = big5, estimator = "MLR")
```

Here is my full code on [Github](https://github.com/hannahtabea/Survey-Development/blob/master/Confirmatory_Factoranalysis.R). Now I get a warning from lavaan:

```
lavaan WARNING:
    The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
    does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
    (= -4.921738e-07) is smaller than zero. This may be a symptom that
    the model is not identified.
```

But when I run `summary(big5_CFA_cmv, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE,  rsquare = TRUE)`, lavaan appeared to end normally and produced good fit statistics.

```
lavaan 0.6-8 ended normally after 77 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                       150
                                                      
                                                  Used       Total
  Number of observations                           498         500
                                                                  
Model Test User Model:
                                               Standard      Robust
  Test Statistic                               2459.635    2262.490
  Degrees of freedom                                885         885
  P-value (Chi-square)                            0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                   1.087
       Yuan-Bentler correction (Mplus variant)                     

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                              9934.617    8875.238
  Degrees of freedom                               990         990
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.119

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.824       0.825
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.803       0.805
                                                                  
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                         0.830
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                            0.810

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)             -31449.932  -31449.932
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.208
      for the MLR correction                                      
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)     -30220.114  -30220.114
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.105
      for the MLR correction                                      
                                                                  
  Akaike (AIC)                               63199.863   63199.863
  Bayesian (BIC)                             63831.453   63831.453
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)        63355.347   63355.347

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.060       0.056
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.057       0.053
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.063       0.059
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.000       0.000
                                                                  
  Robust RMSEA                                               0.058
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower                     0.055
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper                     0.061

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.061       0.061

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Sandwich
  Information bread                           Observed
  Observed information based on                Hessian

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  EXTRA =~                                                              
    EXT1              1.000                               0.455    0.372
    EXT2              1.010    0.323    3.129    0.002    0.459    0.358
    EXT3              0.131    0.301    0.434    0.664    0.059    0.049
    EXT4              1.393    0.430    3.240    0.001    0.633    0.532
    EXT5              0.706    0.168    4.188    0.000    0.321    0.263
    EXT7              1.001    0.183    5.477    0.000    0.455    0.323
    EXT8              1.400    0.545    2.570    0.010    0.637    0.513
    EXT9              1.468    0.426    3.446    0.001    0.667    0.505
    EXT10             1.092    0.335    3.258    0.001    0.497    0.387
  AGREE =~                                                              
    AGR1              1.000                               0.616    0.486
    AGR2              0.721    0.166    4.349    0.000    0.444    0.374
    AGR4              1.531    0.205    7.479    0.000    0.944    0.848
    AGR5              0.999    0.141    7.085    0.000    0.615    0.568
    AGR6              1.220    0.189    6.464    0.000    0.752    0.661
    AGR7              0.743    0.155    4.795    0.000    0.458    0.406
    AGR8              0.836    0.126    6.614    0.000    0.515    0.502
    AGR9              1.292    0.209    6.176    0.000    0.796    0.741
    AGR10             0.423    0.124    3.409    0.001    0.261    0.258
  EMO =~                                                                
    EST1              1.000                               0.856    0.669
    EST2              0.674    0.063   10.626    0.000    0.577    0.485
    EST3              0.761    0.059   12.831    0.000    0.651    0.580
    EST5              0.646    0.081    7.970    0.000    0.552    0.444
    EST6              0.936    0.069   13.542    0.000    0.801    0.661
    EST7              1.256    0.128    9.805    0.000    1.075    0.880
    EST8              1.298    0.131    9.888    0.000    1.111    0.883
    EST9              0.856    0.071   11.997    0.000    0.733    0.602
    EST10             0.831    0.085    9.744    0.000    0.711    0.545
  OPEN =~                                                               
    OPN1              1.000                               0.593    0.518
    OPN2              0.853    0.106    8.065    0.000    0.506    0.492
    OPN3              1.064    0.205    5.186    0.000    0.631    0.615
    OPN5              1.012    0.124    8.161    0.000    0.600    0.654
    OPN6              1.039    0.204    5.085    0.000    0.616    0.553
    OPN7              0.721    0.089    8.115    0.000    0.428    0.481
    OPN8              0.981    0.077   12.785    0.000    0.582    0.474
    OPN9              0.550    0.106    5.187    0.000    0.326    0.332
    OPN10             1.269    0.200    6.332    0.000    0.753    0.772
  CON =~                                                                
    CSN1              1.000                               0.779    0.671
    CSN2              1.151    0.128    8.997    0.000    0.897    0.665
    CSN3              0.567    0.068    8.336    0.000    0.442    0.437
    CSN4              1.054    0.107    9.867    0.000    0.821    0.669
    CSN5              0.976    0.083   11.749    0.000    0.760    0.593
    CSN6              1.393    0.133   10.464    0.000    1.085    0.779
    CSN7              0.832    0.082   10.175    0.000    0.648    0.583
    CSN8              0.684    0.077    8.910    0.000    0.532    0.500
    CSN9              0.938    0.075   12.535    0.000    0.730    0.574
  CMV =~                                                                
    EXT1              1.000                               0.815    0.666
    EXT2              1.074    0.091   11.863    0.000    0.875    0.683
    EXT3              1.112    0.159    7.001    0.000    0.907    0.749
    EXT4              0.992    0.090   11.067    0.000    0.809    0.679
    EXT5              1.194    0.108   11.064    0.000    0.974    0.798
    EXT7              1.253    0.069   18.133    0.000    1.021    0.725
    EXT8              0.733    0.109    6.706    0.000    0.597    0.481
    EXT9              0.857    0.105    8.136    0.000    0.698    0.529
    EXT10             1.010    0.088   11.446    0.000    0.824    0.641
    AGR1              0.047    0.142    0.328    0.743    0.038    0.030
    AGR2              0.579    0.173    3.336    0.001    0.472    0.397
    AGR4             -0.144    0.167   -0.859    0.390   -0.117   -0.105
    AGR5              0.154    0.143    1.075    0.282    0.125    0.116
    AGR6             -0.156    0.161   -0.971    0.332   -0.127   -0.112
    AGR7              0.581    0.178    3.270    0.001    0.474    0.421
    AGR8              0.224    0.123    1.820    0.069    0.183    0.178
    AGR9             -0.043    0.145   -0.299    0.765   -0.035   -0.033
    AGR10             0.540    0.137    3.935    0.000    0.440    0.436
    CSN1             -0.109    0.143   -0.761    0.446   -0.089   -0.077
    CSN2             -0.289    0.150   -1.931    0.054   -0.235   -0.175
    CSN3             -0.064    0.114   -0.561    0.575   -0.052   -0.052
    CSN4              0.041    0.166    0.246    0.806    0.033    0.027
    CSN5              0.009    0.132    0.065    0.948    0.007    0.005
    CSN6             -0.307    0.181   -1.694    0.090   -0.251   -0.180
    CSN7             -0.206    0.132   -1.555    0.120   -0.168   -0.151
    CSN8              0.102    0.137    0.741    0.459    0.083    0.078
    CSN9              0.016    0.151    0.107    0.915    0.013    0.010
    EST1             -0.063    0.167   -0.375    0.708   -0.051   -0.040
    EST2              0.136    0.109    1.248    0.212    0.110    0.093
    EST3             -0.103    0.165   -0.625    0.532   -0.084   -0.075
    EST5              0.117    0.125    0.932    0.351    0.095    0.076
    EST6              0.002    0.158    0.010    0.992    0.001    0.001
    EST7             -0.253    0.239   -1.058    0.290   -0.206   -0.169
    EST8             -0.216    0.243   -0.888    0.375   -0.176   -0.140
    EST9              0.159    0.136    1.168    0.243    0.129    0.106
    EST10             0.331    0.135    2.462    0.014    0.270    0.207
    OPN1             -0.025    0.150   -0.169    0.866   -0.021   -0.018
    OPN2              0.042    0.127    0.332    0.740    0.034    0.033
    OPN3             -0.088    0.110   -0.799    0.424   -0.072   -0.070
    OPN5              0.208    0.139    1.499    0.134    0.170    0.185
    OPN6             -0.012    0.116   -0.102    0.919   -0.010   -0.009
    OPN7              0.146    0.126    1.156    0.248    0.119    0.133
    OPN8             -0.140    0.135   -1.036    0.300   -0.114   -0.093
    OPN9             -0.074    0.103   -0.723    0.470   -0.060   -0.062
    OPN10             0.035    0.138    0.250    0.802    0.028    0.029

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  EXTRA ~~                                                              
    AGREE            -0.096    0.036   -2.692    0.007   -0.342   -0.342
    EMO              -0.089    0.050   -1.782    0.075   -0.228   -0.228
    OPEN             -0.013    0.025   -0.534    0.594   -0.048   -0.048
    CON              -0.060    0.042   -1.440    0.150   -0.170   -0.170
    CMV              -0.063    0.081   -0.783    0.434   -0.171   -0.171
  AGREE ~~                                                              
    EMO              -0.003    0.057   -0.059    0.953   -0.006   -0.006
    OPEN              0.068    0.040    1.712    0.087    0.186    0.186
    CON               0.085    0.047    1.818    0.069    0.177    0.177
    CMV               0.239    0.046    5.185    0.000    0.476    0.476
  EMO ~~                                                                
    OPEN              0.040    0.042    0.957    0.338    0.079    0.079
    CON               0.229    0.050    4.542    0.000    0.343    0.343
    CMV               0.250    0.066    3.810    0.000    0.358    0.358
  OPEN ~~                                                               
    CON               0.058    0.044    1.308    0.191    0.125    0.125
    CMV               0.098    0.069    1.412    0.158    0.202    0.202
  CON ~~                                                                
    CMV               0.185    0.072    2.576    0.010    0.291    0.291

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .EXT1              0.754    0.059   12.680    0.000    0.754    0.503
   .EXT2              0.804    0.065   12.443    0.000    0.804    0.489
   .EXT3              0.658    0.084    7.843    0.000    0.658    0.449
   .EXT4              0.537    0.059    9.162    0.000    0.537    0.379
   .EXT5              0.545    0.049   11.184    0.000    0.545    0.366
   .EXT7              0.892    0.080   11.107    0.000    0.892    0.450
   .EXT8              0.907    0.117    7.740    0.000    0.907    0.589
   .EXT9              0.971    0.099    9.763    0.000    0.971    0.556
   .EXT10             0.867    0.081   10.666    0.000    0.867    0.525
   .AGR1              1.207    0.109   11.087    0.000    1.207    0.750
   .AGR2              0.790    0.085    9.293    0.000    0.790    0.561
   .AGR4              0.439    0.079    5.592    0.000    0.439    0.355
   .AGR5              0.708    0.066   10.721    0.000    0.708    0.602
   .AGR6              0.803    0.075   10.670    0.000    0.803    0.621
   .AGR7              0.628    0.056   11.266    0.000    0.628    0.495
   .AGR8              0.664    0.059   11.168    0.000    0.664    0.631
   .AGR9              0.548    0.056    9.726    0.000    0.548    0.474
   .AGR10             0.647    0.059   10.934    0.000    0.647    0.636
   .EST1              0.935    0.080   11.644    0.000    0.935    0.571
   .EST2              1.026    0.077   13.359    0.000    1.026    0.724
   .EST3              0.869    0.070   12.409    0.000    0.869    0.689
   .EST5              1.196    0.075   15.912    0.000    1.196    0.773
   .EST6              0.826    0.067   12.380    0.000    0.826    0.562
   .EST7              0.453    0.059    7.653    0.000    0.453    0.304
   .EST8              0.457    0.065    7.044    0.000    0.457    0.289
   .EST9              0.862    0.067   12.860    0.000    0.862    0.581
   .EST10             0.986    0.074   13.395    0.000    0.986    0.579
   .OPN1              0.964    0.098    9.828    0.000    0.964    0.735
   .OPN2              0.792    0.070   11.309    0.000    0.792    0.750
   .OPN3              0.670    0.085    7.903    0.000    0.670    0.635
   .OPN5              0.413    0.039   10.466    0.000    0.413    0.490
   .OPN6              0.866    0.099    8.780    0.000    0.866    0.696
   .OPN7              0.574    0.048   11.944    0.000    0.574    0.725
   .OPN8              1.181    0.094   12.627    0.000    1.181    0.784
   .OPN9              0.863    0.083   10.424    0.000    0.863    0.894
   .OPN10             0.376    0.051    7.358    0.000    0.376    0.395
   .CSN1              0.774    0.079    9.836    0.000    0.774    0.574
   .CSN2              1.082    0.099   10.961    0.000    1.082    0.595
   .CSN3              0.837    0.072   11.594    0.000    0.837    0.820
   .CSN4              0.817    0.067   12.117    0.000    0.817    0.542
   .CSN5              1.063    0.077   13.728    0.000    1.063    0.646
   .CSN6              0.856    0.089    9.613    0.000    0.856    0.442
   .CSN7              0.850    0.065   13.025    0.000    0.850    0.688
   .CSN8              0.817    0.057   14.298    0.000    0.817    0.721
   .CSN9              1.079    0.077   13.982    0.000    1.079    0.667
    EXTRA             0.207    0.141    1.467    0.142    1.000    1.000
    AGREE             0.380    0.101    3.744    0.000    1.000    1.000
    EMO               0.732    0.104    7.075    0.000    1.000    1.000
    OPEN              0.352    0.098    3.603    0.000    1.000    1.000
    CON               0.606    0.089    6.792    0.000    1.000    1.000
    CMV               0.665    0.203    3.269    0.001    1.000    1.000

R-Square:
                   Estimate
    EXT1              0.497
    EXT2              0.511
    EXT3              0.551
    EXT4              0.621
    EXT5              0.634
    EXT7              0.550
    EXT8              0.411
    EXT9              0.444
    EXT10             0.475
    AGR1              0.250
    AGR2              0.439
    AGR4              0.645
    AGR5              0.398
    AGR6              0.379
    AGR7              0.505
    AGR8              0.369
    AGR9              0.526
    AGR10             0.364
    EST1              0.429
    EST2              0.276
    EST3              0.311
    EST5              0.227
    EST6              0.438
    EST7              0.696
    EST8              0.711
    EST9              0.419
    EST10             0.421
    OPN1              0.265
    OPN2              0.250
    OPN3              0.365
    OPN5              0.510
    OPN6              0.304
    OPN7              0.275
    OPN8              0.216
    OPN9              0.106
    OPN10             0.605
    CSN1              0.426
    CSN2              0.405
    CSN3              0.180
    CSN4              0.458
    CSN5              0.354
    CSN6              0.558
    CSN7              0.312
    CSN8              0.279
    CSN9              0.333
```

However, there are some negative factor loadings on the common method variance factor. Additionally, extraversion seems to correlate negatively with cmv.

What does this mean? And can I trust the fit statistics or is my model misspecified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me clear up your misinterpretation of the warning message. It refers to the covariance matrix *of estimated parameters* (i.e., `vcov(big5_CFA_cmv)`, from which *SE*s are calculated as the square-roots of the variances on the diagonal), not to the estimates themselves.  Redundancy among estimates can possibly indicate a lack of identification, which you empirically check by saving the model-implied covariance matrix and fitting the same model to it.

```
MI_COV <- lavInspect(big5_CFA_cmv, "cov.ov")
summary(cfa(model = big5_CFAmodel_cmv,
            sample.cov = MI_COV,
            sample.nobs = nobs(big5_CFA_cmv))
```

If your estimates change, that is evidence that your model is not identified.  If the estimates remain the same, the empirical check is inconclusive (i.e., it might still not be identified, but the optimizer just found the same local solution that seemed stable enough to stop searching the parameter space; criteria for inferring convergence are not perfect).

Regarding your model specification, I would doubt it is identified because your CMV factor (on which all indicators load) is allowed to correlate with the trait factors (which are also allowed to correlate). That contradicts the definition of a "method factor", which is something about the way the data were measured that has nothing to do with what is attempted to be measured.  Even when traits are orthogonal to methods, empirical identification becomes tenuous when traits and/or methods are allowed to correlate among each other.  Multitrait--multimethod (MTMM) are notorious for such problems, as are many bifactor models (which are typically one trait and many methods, which your model resembles but is reversed).

> What does this mean?

Your negative (and most positive) CMV loadings are not significant.  Varying around 0 (in both directions) is consistent with the null hypothesis that they are zero.  More noteworthy (and related to my concern above) is that the CMV loadings are significant for all EXT indicators, but only a few others (3 AGR and an EST indicator).  The correlations between CMV and traits really complicates the interpretation, as does using reference indicators.  Before you interpret anything, I would recommend fixing all factor variances to 1 using `std.lv=TRUE` and making CMV orthogonal: `EXTRA + AGREE + EMO + OPEN + CON ~~ 0*CMV`.

However, I still anticipate problems due to estimating so many model parameters with a relatively small sample of 500 (498 after listwise deletion).  That is not nearly a large enough sample to expect 50*51/2 = 1275 (co)variances to be reliably estimated.

Comment: Wow, thank you, Terrence, this is extremely helpful! The original dataset includes more than 1 Mio observations which my computer memory cannot really handle, but I can of course draw a larger subset: Do you think 10.000 observations are sufficient?

Comment: I think 10K would drastically reduce sampling error in the estimated population covariance matrix, but hopefully still be computationally feasible.  Since you are only estimating 150 model parameters (in your posted model), perhaps 1500-2000 would suffice if 10K is prohibitively slow.